# Passing an object to a file included by the same object

Tags: php, class, oop, object, include

I am working on creating a PHP templating engine. I am getting an issue here and I'd like some pointers on how to fix this.

I am trying to use an object on a file that is included by the same object. I've been trying to call $Views->get_link("GitHub"); but it says variable not found, unfortunately. I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Here's the code:

button.view.php:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success " href="<?php $Views->get_link("GitHub"); ?>">
```

views.php:

```
function load_view($view) {

    $viewpath = ZEAM_VIEW_BASEDIR.'/'.$view.ZEAM_VIEW_SUFFIX;

    if (file_exists($viewpath)) {

        include($viewpath); 

    }

}
```

Object starter:

```
// Okay, we're ready to start it up!

require('core.php');

$ZeamEngine = New Zeam(true);

require('modules.php');
require('views.php');

$Modules = New Modules($ZeamEngine);
$Views = New Views($ZeamEngine);

// Custom code for this

$Modules->load_module("ZeamRequisChecker");
$Views->add_link("GitHub", "http://github.com/Alphasquare/Zeam/");
```

How would I do this? If any more info or files are needed just ask.

Comment: Is that really necessary?

Comment: @Sven Your comment is irrelevant and doesn't reflect a supposedly trusted user with a reputation score of 13,639. You're trying to discourage the asker of this question from learning and creating things; that's not a very good way to welcome a new person to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Nathan, I am assuming sven said something about reinventing the wheel regarding creating a templating language, but he said it in a not very constructive way.  Although my comment doesn't address your answer sergio, i feel it is important to look at what is already available, not to discourage you from creating and learning on your own but to understand what the major issues are with creating a templating engine and how the many different PHP templating engines have solved them.

Comment: Don't you guys get the initiative of doing things differently?

Comment: And no, he talked about the amount of engines and stuff.

Comment: It's not exclusively a templating engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `load_view` is a method of class Views, if `button.view.php` is a file which included in method `load_view` -- you need to use `$this` instead of `$Views`.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success " href="<?php $this->get_link("GitHub"); ?>">
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I'll try. One minute.

Comment: Nice bro! I like that answer! Works. @sectus